# Spring integration: read file line by line and call ws for each line

Tags: spring-integration

I would like to retrieve one line at a time from the file, then convert that line to a POJO, then retrieve the next line...
For each line, two web services should be called.

I believe , I should work like this:

```
<int-file:inbound-channel-adapter directory="/tmp/test" 
        id="filesIn" channel="toSplitter">
    <int:poller fixed-delay="5000" />
</int-file:inbound-channel-adapter>

<int:splitter input-channel="toSplitter" output-channel="logger"
    ref="fileSplitter" method="split" />

<int:logging-channel-adapter id="logger" level="WARN"/>

<bean id="fileSplitter" class="foo.FileSplitter" />
```

But according to the [sample](https://gist.github.com/garyrussell/921e366334b5d8d9b8f2) Splitter return a list of messages but I would like to process one only line. Should I use spring batch for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what issue you have, but since version `4.1.2` the Spring Integration provides `FileSplitter` as an out-of-the-box component. Since `4.2` it can be specified as an top-level `<int-file:splitter>` component.

And exactly this one addresses your requirements.

Plus don't forget that you can specify `output-channel` of that  as an `ExecutorChannel` to process the lines from file in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

<s>>But according to the sample</s>

According to which sample?

You are mistaken, the splitter emits a separate message for each split.

Comment: It isn't an answer. Please, consider it to the comment for the question or an existing answer. :-)

Comment: There is nothing in that "sample" that suggests it emits a list of messages; each line is emitted one-at-a-time. That code was the basis for the `FileSplitter` that is now in the framework as @ArtemBilan points out in his answer.